# Can't login into webmin

Tags: ubuntu, login, users

I bought VPS server and now I install webmin on it.
so when I wanna login into webmin by http://88.198.196.118:10000/ it will redirect to https://static.88-198-196-118.clients.your-server.de:10000/ address,I try to login into it by my SSH username and password (which one I usually connect to ssh of my server by putty) but I con't do it.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to connect to the server at 88.198.196.118 using the http protocol you get this message

```
This web server is running in SSL mode. Try the URL ...
```

If you try to connect using https then you can get to your server so

```
https:88.198.196.118:10000
```

should do the trick.